# Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TObject> because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I have the following

```
    public AttributeCollection(string objectUrn) : this(new Uri(objectUrn)) { }
    public AttributeCollection(Uri objectUrn) : base(() => Service.FindAllByObjectUrn(objectUrn).ToList())       
    {
        ObjectUrn = objectUrn;
    }
```

The lambda is throwing the error in the subject. The strange thing is, prior to the conversion to Visual Studio 2010 from Visual Studio 2008, the code compiles fine. It's still targeting .NET framework 3.5. I don't understand what possibly could have changed from migrating to 2010 that would affect this. Any pointers?

**Edit**
The base class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class OneToManyCollection<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ISerializable
{
    public OneToManyCollection();
    public OneToManyCollection(Func<IEnumerable<T>> lazyLoader);
    public OneToManyCollection(ICollection<T> items);
    public OneToManyCollection(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);

    protected virtual ICollection<T> Added { get; }
    public virtual int Count { get; }
    public virtual bool IsDirty { get; }
    public virtual bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    protected virtual ICollection<T> Items { get; }
    protected virtual ICollection<T> Removed { get; }

    public virtual void Add(T newItem);
    public virtual void Clear();
    protected virtual void ClearIsDirty();
    public virtual bool Contains(T item);
    public virtual void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex);
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
    public virtual bool Remove(T oldItem);
    public abstract void Save();
}
```

Comment: "The lambda is throwing the error in the subject." Is that an exception? If so, exception can stacktrace. If not what is the full line and error of the compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to tell C# what the type of your lambda is (you'll have to change `T` to the actual type):

```
public AttributeCollection(Uri objectUrn) :
    base((Func<IEnumerable<T>>)
         (() => Service.FindAllByObjectUrn(objectUrn).ToList()))
{
    ObjectUrn = objectUrn;
}
```

Also, note that the `.ToList()` wouldn't be necessary because either way you should have an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your lambda expresion returns a `List<Uri>` and your constructor expects `Func<IEnumerable<Uri>>`. The compiler might get confused what delegate your lambda expression  is.

Try changing your code to this.

```
    public AttributeCollection(Uri objectUrn) : base(new Func<IEnumerable<Uri>>(() => Service.FindAllByObjectUrn(objectUrn).ToList()))       
    {
        ObjectUrn = objectUrn;
    }
```